# cannot call function from other function

Tags: objective-c

I need to get abs. the value of NSDecimalNumber. And I use pre-defined function for that:

```
     - (NSDecimalNumber *)aDN: (NSDecimalNumber *)num {
         if ([num compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
           // negative value
           return [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalNumberBySubtracting:num];
         } else {
           return num;
           }
       }
```

However when I try to call it from other function. Namely

```
      - (void) prepareForSeque....
          wordD=aDN(number);
```

I get the error: " Implicit declaration of function 'aDN' is invalid in C99'

Can you give me some pointers how to troubleshoot this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be confusing languages. It looks like you should have

```
wordD = [self aDN:number];
```

(Assuming the class hosting the method is the current class and not a category on decimal number which might make more sense...)

Comment: Thanks! Yep, objective C is not my language of preference. I'll have to make sure to be more careful with this in future.